# python warp socket fail

Tags: python, ssl

I'm trying to code a server using ssl, but there is an error I don't understand.
Here is the code :

```
import socket, ssl, select, sys, exceptions

def do_something(connstream, data):
if not data:
    return False
connstream.write(data)
print data
return True

def deal_with_client(connstream):
data = connstream.read()
# null data means the client is finished with us
while data:
    if not do_something(connstream, data):
        # we'll assume do_something returns False
        # when we're finished with client
        break
    data = connstream.read()
# finished with client

bindsocket = socket.socket()
bindsocket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 240))
bindsocket.listen(5)



while True:
newsocket, fromaddr = bindsocket.accept()
try:
    connstream = ssl.wrap_socket(newsocket, server_side=True, certfile="E:\oromenetwork\test\cert", keyfile="E:\oromenetwork\test\key", ca_certs=None, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
    connstream.write("Bonjour")
    deal_with_client(connstream)
except ssl.SSLError as e:
    print "warp error "
    print e
    newsocket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    newsocket.close()
    exit()
except exceptions.TypeError as e:
    print "other error"
    #print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    print e
    newsocket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    newsocket.close()
    exit()
```

So I test it with  openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:240

And here is the error : [Errno 336265218]  _ssl.c:351 error:140B0002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:system lib

I already checked the permission and the path

Answer (score 4):

In the strings to your certfile and keyfile, you use `"\t",` which is an alias for Tab. Either escape the backslashes (as `"\\"`), use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.path.html#os.path.join), or [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

```
connstream = ssl.wrap_socket(newsocket, server_side=True,
                             certfile=r"E:\oromenetwork\test\cert",
                             #       v^
                             keyfile=r"E:\oromenetwork\test\key",
                             ca_certs=None,ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
```